# ShellScript Rotate rectangulous text by 45°

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, rotation

I need to do a script for bash to solve the word game for 8 directions. I have managed to make some code, but the last thing I am stuck on, is how to rotate the table to find the words in all directions. 90° is not a problem, but 45°... I think awk could help but I am not really good at it.
Thanks.

**Example:**

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
```

=>

```
a
eb
ifc
 jgd
  kh
   l
```

**Example 2:**

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
```

=>

```
a
fb
kgc
 lhd
  mie
   nj
    o
```

**Example 3:**

```
abc
defg
hi
```

=>

```
a
db
hec
 if
   g
```

Comment: Please , you should add examples: 3words x 5letters , 3words x each word with different length, if is it possible?, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="" }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        a[NR,i]=$i
    }
    numCols = (NF>numCols?NF:numCols)
    numRows = NR
}
END {
    rowNr=1
    for (colNr=1;colNr<=numCols;colNr++) {
        for (;rowNr<=numRows;rowNr++) {
            printf "%*s", colNr-1, ""
            for (delta=0;delta<rowNr;delta++) {
                printf "%s%s", a[rowNr-delta,colNr+delta], (delta<(rowNr-1)?FS:RS)
            }
        }
        rowNr=numRows
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1
a
eb
ifc
 jgd
  kh
   l
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file2
a
fb
kgc
 lhd
  mie
   nj
    o
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file3
a
db
hec
 if
  g
```

wrt the comments below from @JoseRicardoBustosM. suggesting that the above does not produce the desired output from one of his sample inputs, here's the suggested `input4`:

```
$ cat input4
Jose
y
Ricardo
y
Gloriset
```

and the above script run on it:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input4
J
yo
Rs
yie
Gc
 la
  or
   rd
    io
     s
      e
       t
```

and here's a modified script to inject blank chars when none exist IF that was the desired behavior which I think is extremely unlikely:

```
$ cat tst2.awk
BEGIN { FS="" }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        a[NR,i]=$i
    }
    numCols = (NF>numCols?NF:numCols)
    numRows = NR
}
END {
    rowNr=1
    for (colNr=1;colNr<=numCols;colNr++) {
        for (;rowNr<=numRows;rowNr++) {
            printf "%*s", colNr-1, ""
            for (delta=0;delta<rowNr;delta++) {
                printf "%s%s", ((rowNr-delta,colNr+delta) in a ? a[rowNr-delta,colNr+delta] : " "), (delta<(rowNr-1)?FS:RS)
            }
        }
        rowNr=numRows
    }
}

$ awk -f tst2.awk input4
J
yo
R s
yi e
G c
 l a
  o r
   r d
    i o
     s
      e
       t
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `perl` instead of `awk`. `Perl` is very powerful in processing texts, and the syntax is quite `C`-like.

As far as I understand what 'rotating a text by 45°' means, the following script performs such a rotation:

`rotate_text_45.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @input = <>;
my $lines_count = scalar @input;

my $global_max_diag = 0;
for my $i (0 .. scalar @input - 1){
    chomp $input[$i];
    $input[$i] = [split //, $input[$i]];
    my $max_diag = $i + scalar(@{$input[$i]}) - 1;
    $global_max_diag = $max_diag if $max_diag > $global_max_diag;
}

for my $diag (0 .. $global_max_diag){
    for my $i (0 .. $diag){
        next if $diag - $i >= $lines_count;
        $input[$diag - $i][$i] = ' ' unless defined $input[$diag - $i][$i];
        print $input[$diag - $i][$i];
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Assuming the input file is as follows:

```
$ cat in.txt 
iftkn
iarwp
cooop
froas
blmaz
```

the script produces this result:

```
$ ./rotate_text_45.pl in.txt
i
if
cat
fork
brown
loop 
map  
as   
z
```

To perform rotation by 135° or 225° I suggest rotation by 90° (180°) and then rotation by 45°.

Comment: I would suggest using `awk` instead of `perl`. `Awk` is very powerful in processing texts, and the syntax is quite C-like.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  sum = 0;
}
{
  words[NR] = $0;
  sum += length($0);
}
END{
  cant_words = length(words);
  for(i=1; i<=cant_words; i++){
    flag[i] = 2-i;
  }
  cont_letter = 0;
  row = 1;
  while(cont_letter<sum){
    out = "";
    for(i=0; i<row-cant_words; i++){
      out = out" ";
    }
    cont_space = 0;
    for(i=cant_words; i>=1; i--){
      if(flag[i] >= 1 && flag[i] <= length(words[i])){
        for(j=0; j<cont_space; j++){
          out=out" "
        }
        cont_space = 0;
        out=out""substr(words[i],flag[i],1);
        cont_letter = cont_letter + 1;
      }else{
        if(flag[i] > length(words[i])){
          cont_space = cont_space + 1;
        }
      }
      flag[i] = flag[i]+1;
    }
    print out;
    row = row + 1;
  }
}
' input
```

input1:

```
abcd 
efgh 
ijkl
```

output1:

```
a
eb
ifc
 jgd
  kh
   l
```

input2

```
abc 
defg 
hi
```

output2

```
a
db
hec
 if 
   g
```

input3

```
abc 
defg 
hi
jklm
```

output3

```
a
db
hec
jif 
 k g
  l  
   m
```

input4

```
Jose
y
Ricardo
y
Gloriset
```

output4

```
J
yo
R s
yi e
G c
 l a
  o r
   r d
    i o
     s
      e
       t
```